# Overflowing title in review queue for Suggested Edits

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

Stepped into my review queue for Suggested Edits and saw this issue.
[image: questions title overflowing]

I suspect this has got to do with the `word-break` attribute not being set correctly, as it can be fixed by using `word-break: break-all` or `word-break: break-word`

##### Break-All

[image: Fixing overflow using break-all]

##### Break-Word

[image: Fixing overflow using break-word]

Comment: Previously [also reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363457/665544).